How do I get a graphic overlaying text?
I'm wanting to get a graphic like the attached to overlay on top of text. Not sure the best way, is it via CSS or image?
I have tried using z-index but I'm just not sure on what is the best approach for it. It looks like that website uses Node Shapes when I inspect the code.


Try with relative container and inside of it the text and the superposed image as absolute object.

@PsychoMx do you mean like this for example?
HTML:

test
  
CSS:
.test {
position:relative;
}
.doodle-test {
position: absolute;
}

Yes, something like that as you say in your post, i think its more flexible to do like that

For some reason it's not overlaying, do I need to be using z-index? (excuse my bad formatting of the code ha)

Yes, besides the absolute property you must add a z-index to superimpose the image on the text, if you don't like the position of the image you can play with the positions of the image using top, left, bottom and right.

A simple solution could be using the image as background image und just show text in that HTML container.
You'll have to fine tune dimensions, for example adjusting container dimensions to image dimensions. In the example it's just background-size: contain;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    .image-background-container {
      width: 20rem;
      height: 5rem;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
      background-size: contain;
    }
    
    .text-overlay {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-background-container">
    <div class="text-overlay">
      Hello plain text over background image.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Nice test image URL, thanks DarkBee :-)
